# java: cannot find symbol; symbol: variable length

Tags: java

I apologize if this is too beginner of a question. I understand that some how my [ Object o ] is out of scope, that is why it cannot find the symbol.

However, I can't seem to fix the problem. I'm completely unsure of where it went wrong. I believe this is the last problem in my Assignment, and it's due midnight.

Any help would be greatly appreciated :)

```java
public class Square implements Shape
{
    double length;

    public Square(double length)
    {
        this.length = length;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString()
    {
        return "Square";
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object o)
    {
        if (o == null)
            return false;
        if(this.getClass() != o.getClass())
            return false;
        if (o.length == this.length)
            return true;
        else
            return false;
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode()
    {
        return (int)length % 50;
    }
    public double getPerimeter()
    {
        return length * 4;
    }
}
```

> C:\Users\RimZ\IdeaProjects\Assignment1\src\Square.java
>
> Error:(24, 22) java: cannot find symbol
>     symbol:   variable length
>     location: variable o of type java.lang.Object

```
if (o.*length* == this.length)
            return true;
```

^ thats where the problem is

Comment: `Object`s don't have field `length`. Cast the object and check.

Comment: So any square with a multiple of 50 length would be considered `==`? At least, that's what your hashcode implementation says

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to cast your `Object` into a `Square`:

```
Square otherSquare = (Square) o;
...
if (otherSquare.length == this.length)
    return true;
```